# How much time would take to lift a person to 0.1m above floor of elevator?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, acceleration

How much time would take to lift a person to height $h$ above floor of elevator if the elevator goes down with acceleration $a$, where:
$$h=0.1 \; \text{m}$$
$$ a=13 \; \text{m}/\text{s}^2 $$
How to solve it? What is the general equation for this system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  The floor goes down at $13 m/s^2$, the person goes down at $g \approx 9.81 m/s^2$, so the net acceleration is?

Comment: 13-9.8=3.2 m/s^2 . S=(a*t^2)/2 . t=Sqrt[2*S/a] . t=0.25 s

Comment: Looks good to me